# how to convert sql server database schema plus the data in all tables into xml form

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, database

i want to convert the data in database in xml form 
using c# i already converted in ino xml form but the it does not give me the information about primary and foreign keys in schema

my code is

```
 string[] b = GetAllTables();//array that gives me the name of tables

  foreach (string c in b)
    {
      string sqlText = "SELECT * FROM  " + c;
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlText, myCon);
      da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      da.Fill(customer,c);

      foreach (DataTable dt1 in customer.Tables)
        {
          for (int curRow = 0; curRow < dt1.Rows.Count; curRow++)
          {
            for (int curCol = 0; curCol < dt1.Columns.Count; curCol++)
            {  
              dt1.Rows[curRow][curCol].ToString();  
              // System.IO.StreamWriter xmlSW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Customer.xml");
            }
          }
        }
     }

  string xmlDS = customer.GetXml();
  customer.WriteXml(xmlSW, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
  MessageBox.Show("successfully writed");
  xmlSW.Close();
```

Comment: In MS SQL Server you can add at the end of your query "SELECT * FROM Table FOR XML AUTO" as well as "SELECT * FROM Table FOR XML RAW". Try that on your SQL Editor and see if the result helps your final  objectives.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use XElement class and set the attributes of the xml file like the following(just a example):
SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=3BDALLAH-PC;Initial Catalog=XMLC;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;");
thisConnection.Open();

```
XElement eventsGive =
    new XElement("data",
        from c in ?????? 
        select new XElement("event",
            new XAttribute("start", c.start),
            new XAttribute("end",c.eend),
            new XAttribute("title",c.title),
            new XAttribute("Color",c.Color),
            new XAttribute("link",c.link)));

Console.WriteLine(eventsGive);
```

Then you put your column label of the database and its name in the xml file.

Regards,

Otacon.